# Vb.Net Quiz Application Multiple Views

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, dynamic-usercontrols

I am developing a quiz application in VB.Net . The UI is shown below. 
The questions are generated randomly from a set of 500 questions and stored into an array. The questions are also stored in an arrray.
[image: User Interface]

When the user clicks next another question and set of answers loads from the array "Questions".
The user should be able to go Back and go Next  , when the user goes back he/she should see the value of  answer for that question

Which VB.Net Control(s)  should i use for this pls . Cause i was using multiple forms initially but it became inefficient since the questions were more than 5 Qusetions

Comment: cant you just change the question and answer text (and which answer they selected, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set new text to label on button click. To keep track of previous question, store the id of it somewhere. Settings for example.